# TypeError: Object of type module is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, dump

I use the json.dumps() to pack datas as follow,
using complex_signal.tolist() or str(complex_signal) is same result too;

```py
import json

#send to kafka
def Send(complex_signal, frequency, time):
    signal = {  # 
        "time": time,
        "frequency": frequency,
        "complex_signal": complex_signal# this is a ndarray type
    }

    msg = json.dumps(signal)
    producer.produce('topic_test', key=None, value=msg)
```

console out :raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.**class**.**name**} '
TypeError: Object of type module is not JSON serializable

JSON,I use rtl-sdr to get signal and send it to kafka .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `producer` is not defined.  what is this ?